# Delete null values on an Array

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, for-loop, isnullorempty

I would like to send an object with JSON, I iterate this object with a for loop. My JSON sent is correct but the problem is there is null values in the array. I thinks it's linked with the `myValue.children[index]= item;`
I tried .filter() method but it didn't resolve my problem because array returned is empty. I also tried a condition but I just have 4 values detected.
This is the JSON I receive :

```
{
  "name":"object",
  "children":[
    {
      "name":"myName",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"aNumber",
          "size":12345
        }
      ]
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "name":"myName",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"aNumber",
          "size":12345
        }
      ]
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "name":"myName",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"aNumber",
          "size":12345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"myName",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"aNumber",
          "size":12345
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my code :

```
function myFunction(index, tabItem , callback){
    var result = '';
    var myValue = {};
    var childrenTicket = [];
    myValue.name = "object";
    myValue.children = childrenTicket;
    for (index in tabItem) {
        try{
            var currentItem = tabItem[index];
            var Object =currentItem.issuelinks.issuelinktype.outwardlinks.issuelink;
            for(var SeveralObject in Object) {
                var item = {};
                var specificObject = Object[SeveralObject]; 
                var main = specificObject._;
                var id = specificObject.$.id;
                var descriptionObject = {};
                descriptionObject.name = id;
                descriptionObject.size = 12345;
                item.name = main;
                if (myValue.children[index] == undefined){
                    console.log('undefined detected'); 
                }
                myValue.children[index]= item;
                //result = result + (myValue);
                item.children = [descriptionObject];
                sendJson(myValue);
                callback(result);
            }
        } catch(ignored){
        }
    } return result;
}
```

Hope you will can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `underscore` module and use its `compact` method.

Link: http://underscorejs.org/#compact

Comment: I use that on itemTicket but as .filter(), an emtpy Array is returned...     `var newChild = _.compact(itemTicket);
                sendJson(newChild);`

Comment: How do you use it? I've just tested it with your JSON and it works just fine

Comment: I use it on itemTicket, I create a new variable and I send this new.

Comment: I use it like `var ticket = your JSON; ticket.children = _.compact(ticket.children)`

Comment: I have an empty array :                 `var ticket = itemTicket;
                ticket.children = _.compact(ticket.children);
                sendJson(ticket);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj[i] === null || obj[i] === undefined) {
    delete obj[i];
  }
}
```

`obj` is your JSON object.

Comment: I already try that on `itemTicket.children[index]` but it doesn't works, do you thinks I use it on the good object ?

Comment: You need to pass the entire JSON object as the `obj`.

Comment: I use it on my JSON file but the result is exactly the same                 `for (var i in itemTicket) {
                    if (itemTicket[i] === null || itemTicket[i] === undefined) {
                        delete itemTicket[i];
                    }
                }
                sendJson(itemTicket);`

Answer (score 0):

you can delete null values like this

```
    for (var ite in ObjJson)
            {
                if(ObjJson[ite]==null)
                {
                console.log('ys null');
                delete ObjJson[ite];
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Same problem, I use it juste before to send and any null value is deleted :                 `for (var ite in itemTicket)
                {
                    if(itemTicket[ite]==null)
                    {
                        console.log('ys null')
                        delete itemTicket[ite];
                    }
                }
                sendJson(itemTicket);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using underscore.js

```
_.compact(array)
```

It will remove all the null, false, undefined etc values.

Advantage of using underscore.js over writing a loop or something on your own is underscore.js functions will be faster than your loops and the chances of errors will be less.

Comment: I highly doubt underscore's loops will be faster that one you write on your own. Why do you say that?